# Magnetic field lines due to two long parallel wires

Tags: magnetic-fields, vector-fields, visualization

There are two current carrying wires A and B both with same current (i) in same direction (outwards) , the rough representation of magnetic field lines looks like the diagram. O is the mid point of AB. I want to know what the field lines look like near to the point O

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$O$ is a neutral point a point where the magnetic field is zero.
The magnetic field around the neutral point is small compared with the magnetic field near the wires so the density if magnetic field lines would be smaller than around the wires.
So as a sketch, something like this?

[image]

Comment: Also another thing the field just above the point O will be directed towards the left and the field just left to the point O will be directed upwards and magnetic field lines can't intersect each other. I wanted to know how the lines look just near to O (tending to O)

Comment: @sujaankumar The diagram above exactly mirrors what you have written in your comment about the direction of the magnetic field lines.  So imagine the centre part of the diagram magnified and some more field lines put in coming ever closer to the neutral point. The general shape of those lines will still be the same.